# how to store array data with commas in db?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Iam trying to insert Array data (ie., checkbox values) into Mysql db (using Phpmyadmin)

when I try to store, iam getting as 'Array' for the field "forms" in db..

please someone tell me what changes I have to do for the below code, so I can store all the array values (seperated with commas in my db)

here is the code:

```
if(isset($_POST['forms']) && $_POST['forms']!=''){
        $table = $wpdb->prefix . "eshop_orders";
        $forms=$wpdb->escape($_POST['forms']);


        $query1=$wpdb->query("UPDATE $table SET forms='$forms' where checkid='$checkid' limit 1");
    }
```

waiitng for replies..

Comment: The best idea is to create a proper database definition that identifies the different form fields as columns, or a properly normalised table structure

Answer (score 1):

Since `$forms` is an array, you either need to [`serialize()`](http://php.net/serialize) it or convert it into a string before inserting.  Which method you choose is up to you and what makes more sense.

```
// convert to comma separated string
$forms = $wpdb->escape( implode(',', $_POST['forms']) );

// or

// serialize the PHP array, use unserialize when you retrieve it
$forms = $wpdb->escape( serialize($_POST['forms']) );
```

Comment: after using comma seperated string: i have got this error in browser:  Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/bob147/public_html/mywebsite.com/wp-content/plugins/eshop-extras/eshop-extras.php on line 170 

and its showing empty for the field 'forms' in db..

Comment: That probably means that `$_POST['forms']` is not an array when you get that error.

Comment: Before i didnt use implode, its storing as 'Array' for the field 'forms' in db.. then why its stored as 'Array' in db..? Iam confused...

Comment: If the wordpress escape function treats the argument as a string, it would turn an array into the string 'Array'.  What does `var_dump($_POST['forms']);` show?

Comment: So for whatever reason, the data is being sent to PHP as just a string that says `Array`.  Unless something modified `$_POST['forms']` earlier in the code, the data doesn't appear to be getting sent over properly.

Comment: YOu mean Iam unable to retrive values from my selected checkboxes..?

this is my html code:

 <input type="checkbox" name="forms[]" value="ArticlesOrderForm"> <b>Articles Order Form </b><br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="forms[]" value="PressReleasesForm"> <b> Press Releases Form </b><br>

Comment: The HTML looks correct, but `var_dump($_POST['forms'])` should show an actual array, rather than `string(5) "Array"` if all was working properly.  Somewhere the array must be getting converted to a string.

Comment: i removed this:  $forms=$wpdb->escape($_POST['forms']);

and I just checked as "echo  $_POST['forms'];"  // OUTPUT: Array

Comment: That makes sense, if you try to echo an array PHP returns the string 'Array' since there is no defined way of echo'ing an array.  I'm still confused though why the var_dump shows a string, not an array.